# How to authenticate user from another localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm designing 2 websites (`localhost:44300` and `localhost:44301`). The first to upload images and the second to store the images as an image hosting.

In the Home controller of the second website, I've declared:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImages()
{
   //logic...
}
```

Script in the first website:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://localhost:44301/Home/UploadImages',
   type: 'POST'
}).done(function (data) {
   //logic...
})
```

That's great, but: What's happen if there is a request to `localhost:44301` which NOT sent by `localhost:44300` (another website)?

`UploadImages()` method still accepts that request and continues uploading.

I think about `account`. But how can I login from a localhost to another localhost? I cannot put `username` and `password` into the ajax. It's easy to read by attacker.

I have 2 questions:

Is it good if I use account in this case? If not, can you give me some tips?

Thank you!

Comment: Why couldn't the two sites share the same database back-end? That would seem to be the easiest solution to my mind here.

Comment: @JBKing That's new to me. Can you provide me a link to more understand it? Don't have many things with keyword `database back-end` in google search

Comment: I guess ajax script is called from client's browser not Server1 right?

Comment: @RamazanBinarbasi Yes. It's in client side (the first site). it will be sent to server side (the second site) when submitting.

Comment: @HappyCoding, the 2 sites share the same DB and thus cross site scripting issues can be minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. It's very easy:

> Check for `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

If AbsoluteUri starts with ... (come from ...), it should be a valid request.

Example:

```
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://localhost:44300/"))
{
   //logic...
}
```

or specific domain name:

```
if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https://site1.com/"))
{
   //logic...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual question is dealing with handling server to server authentication between applications not specifically allowing internal access and rejecting external.

Seeing the discussion above between OP and JB King. What I'd truly recommend is that you use [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) or Amazon S3 storage. Then you can easily read or write the binary data between your applications.

The other alternative is just use regular Forms Authentication but you have site1 post the username and password to the login action and get back the auth cookie in the response. You need to just hold onto the auth cookie and pump it into any outbound requests from site1 to site2.

---

Old answer:

If you want to execute authorization on whether the request is local you want to implement a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`

It would look similar to

```
public class LocalOnlyAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (false == filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
            filterContext.Result = 
               new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Origin is forbidden");
        }
    }
}
```

and you would apply it

```
[LocalOnlyAuth]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Comment: If I use `localhost:44302`, it may be accepted. Because the IP address still 127.0.0.1 (`localhost`). Your solution looks good. But it won't work if I upload both of 2 websites to azure (different IP from 127.0.0.1)

Comment: "But it won't work if I upload both of 2 websites to azure" it wouldn't work in Azure because the requests aren't local.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for something like this: `if request is sent by the first website, continue uploading. Else exit.` Your solution means: Accept all requests which are sent by local.

Comment: Bingo. +1 for ` hold onto the auth cookie and pump it into any outbound requests from site1 to site2.`. I will use ajax from site1 to make a request to server1 to get a specific hash string. Then, send it to server2. Server2 will decrypt it. If matched, continue uploading. Is it good?

Comment: If you use ajax from site1 to site2 you might need to look into CORS support and origin policies but it's not difficult to setup https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+cross-origin+resource+sharing&oq=asp.net+mvc+cross-origin+resource+sharing

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'll:

- Make server 2 just for image access
- Share a Folder to Server 1 (Windows folder share)
- Upload image to server 1 always and move it to server 2's related share on server side

This way you'll have a readonly image server wich is updated only from server 1 within LAN share.

If this is not applicable (you don't want to upload anything to server1) check out Load Balancing + Authentication questions like this one ([Does Forms Authentication work with Web Load Balancers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357850/does-forms-authentication-work-with-web-load-balancers)). So that you can also expand your servers to be more than 1 + 1.

Comment: Thank you! I understand you mean. Can you tell me how to make a `LAN share` between `www.site1.com` and `www.site2.com`? With localhost, I think I can do that until upload to azure.

Comment: If both servers are not on same LAN, but both of them is yours, then you need to share client's authentication. (Server2 has nothing to do with Server1 I guess? Client is posting a file to Server2, where Server1 does not even know about this post). You have to authenticate client on server2 then, like in load balancing scenarios.