Request.IsAuthenticated is always false at login time in load balanced environment
I have an ASP.NET 4.8 application which was written long time ago and is working perfectly into current production load balancer environment. After I enhanced the application that works fine on one server. When applications deployed to the production load balanced servers, the application did not work as expected. It does not turn true of Request.IsAuthenticated variable after redirect to the main page from login page.
Application uses forms authentication.
<authentication mode="Forms">       
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="20" .../></authentication> 

I am not able to find the root cause and solution. How can I figure out the issue?
It is in production issue. I am stuck. Any kind of help or hints or solution is appreciated.

You'll have to set the machine key to be the same and the name to be the same on both machines. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357864/1807452
